# Two Dynamic Headers for the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, ampscript, dynamic, header-bar

We have a requirement where we need a different header for the same email based on the condition in the code which triggers that email.
So in our ET account there are two headers set up

1. HeaderOne
2. HeaderTwo

We need to use one of those header based on the condition in the code for Customerorder  the email. What could be the ways we can get that.

Also can we use a dynamic variable inside dynamic variable?  By that I mean

`%%=contentareabyname("my contents\Headers\%%HeaderName%%")=%%`

Where HeaderName will be coming from the code and which could be 
HeaderOne or  HeaderTwo

Comment: You could have multiple approaches here. 1. Have 2 email templates created say template 1 having header 1 and template 2 having header 2 and based the decision criteria in your code attach the template to an outgoing email. 2. The other approach is to use a Visualforce email template and construct the email body and header dynamically using html. In this approach use the decision criteria from the code to dynamically apply or build the header. Hope this helps.

Comment: In order to use dynamic variables inside template you will need to use Visualforce email templates in combination with <apex:variable or controller variables i

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
%%[

var @headerName
set @headerName = "my contents\Headers\"

/* whatever condition here*/
if (@a == @b) then
  /* use AttributeValue() to handle null values */
  set @headerName = concat(@headerName,AttributeValue("HeaderOne"))
else
  set @headerName = concat(@headerName,AttributeValue("HeaderTwo"))
endif

]%%
%%=contentareabyname(@headerName)=%%
```

Comment: @CodeDiva, did this answer your question?